# Razor Multiple Pages/Models (Wizard): How to Show Element if Checkbox "true" on another Page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am using a wizard that is saving responses with `TempData` in cookies as I step through pages. There is one Razor Page that handles the wizard steps. All the other pages just have view model properties (they are not individual pages in themselves).

On one Razor Page I have an `@Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.CheckBox1)`; that page's model has `public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }`

Now, on a second Razor Page, if `Checkbox1` is checked (`true`) then I would like to display another set of elements.

I don't want to lose the data if I check for it, so I thought `Peek` might work, but I can't figure out how to check if the other page's property was checked:

`@if (TempData.Peek("CheckBox1").ToString() == "true") { //show elements }`

Getting object reference error above. Just not sure how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

When checkbox is changed,you can post data to handler of razorpage1,and then set tempdata and redirect to razorpage2,if you only set checkbox1 data,and don't redirect to razorpage2,razorpage2 cannot get the data,here is a demo:

Test1.cshtml:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" asp-page-handler="SetTempData"> 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBox1)
</form>
<script>
    $("#CheckBox1").change(function () {
        $("#myform").submit();
    })
</script>
```

Test1.cshtml.cs:

```
 public class Test1Model : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostSetTempData() {
        TempData["CheckBox1"] = CheckBox1;
        return RedirectToPage("Test2");

    }
}
```

Test2.cshtml:

```
@if (TempData.ContainsKey("CheckBox1")&&TempData.Peek("CheckBox1").ToString() == "True")
{
    <h1>CheckBox1:@TempData.Peek("CheckBox1").ToString()</h1>
}
```

Test2.cshtml.cs:

```
public class Test2Model : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]
Here is another demo without TempData:

Test1.cshtml:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" asp-page-handler="SetTempData"> 
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBox1)
</form>
<script>
    $("#CheckBox1").change(function () {
        $("#myform").submit();
    })
</script>
```

Test1.cshtml.cs:

```
public class Test1Model : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostSetTempData() {
       
        return RedirectToPage("Test2", new { CheckBox1 = CheckBox1 });

    }
}
```

Test2.cshtml:

```
@if (Model.CheckBox1)
{
<h1>CheckBox1:@Model.CheckBox1</h1>
}
```

Test2.cshtml.cs:

```
public class Test2Model : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(Name = "CheckBox1", SupportsGet = true)]
        public bool CheckBox1 { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]